# XSLT not generating expected output

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

**Input XML:**

```
<derivatives>
    <derivative id="4" name="Audio Content">

        <operator id="1" name="Reliance">
            <referenceCode code="62033815">
                <mobileCircle id="1" name="Maharashtra"/>
            </referenceCode>
        </operator>

        <operator id="22" name="Aircel">
            <referenceCode code="811327">
                <mobileCircle id="1" name="Maharashtra"/>
            </referenceCode>
        </operator>

    </derivative>
</derivatives>
```

**Expected Output XML:**

```
<hellotune>
    <operator>Aircel</operator>
    <vcode>811327</vcode>
</hellotune>
```

**Current output (which is wrong):**

```
<hellotune>
    <operator>Aircel</operator>
    <vcode/>
</hellotune>
```

**XSL (which is not working):**

```
<xsl:if test="derivatives/derivative/operator[@name='Aircel']">
    <hellotune>
        <operator>Aircel</operator>
        <vcode><xsl:value-of select="referenceCode/@code"/></vcode>
    </hellotune>
</xsl:if>
```

**Note:** Using XSL v1.0. Not mentioned the complete XSL for brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the XSL you provided, it can be presumed that the context node is the root node, but starting from the root node, the path `referenceCode/@code` does not match anything in your input. Appending `derivatives/derivative/operator/` before that path would succeed in finding a referenceCode `@code` attribute, but it would find the wrong one. Try this push-style approach:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="derivatives/derivative/operator[@name='Aircel']" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="operator">
    <hellotune>
        <operator><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></operator>
        <vcode><xsl:value-of select="referenceCode/@code"/></vcode>
    </hellotune>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath xpression in the element `<vcode>` is not referring to any node in the input document. The best way to match all the nodes is to use

> //

like in your code you can use

> //referenceCode/@code 
>   (but this is only for information purpose and using same can't get your result).

you can try this way:

```
<xsl:template match="/">

<hellotune>
    <xsl:for-each select="//operator">
            <xsl:if test="./@name='Aircel'">
                <operator><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></operator>
                <vcode><xsl:value-of select="referenceCode/@code"/></vcode>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
</hellotune>
</xsl:template>
```

Hope this helps :)